# Why no std::string overload for std::to_string

Tags: c++, c++11

The title says it all really. Why did they choose to not have a

```
namespace std
{
    std::string to_string(const std::string&)
}
```

overload?

I have an program that can query some data by row index or row name; ideal for templates. Until I try to construct an error message if a row being accessed is missing:

```
template <typename T>
int read(T nameOrIndex)
{
    if (!present(nameOrIndex))
    {
        // This does not compile if T is std::string.
        throw std::invalid_argument("Missing row: " + std::to_string(nameOrIndex));
    }
}
```

I could add my own overload to the `std` namespace but that's not ideal.

Comment: It's probably just missing due to oversight.

Comment: Your code will not compile if `T` is any number of other types too. What about all of those? Should there be a `to_string` implementation that returns some string for arbitrary types? Instead of adding `to_string` overloads to `std` (which is illegal), I'd create my own `to_string` overloads in the same namespace as `read`. Delegate to `std::to_string` from that, and return the argument as is from the overload that takes `std::string const&`.

Comment: `std::to_string` converts built-in numeric types to strings. There's no corresponding need to "convert" strings to strings because they already are strings.

Comment: As I understand, `to_string` is basically a safe interface to the C formatting utilities that conceals the buffer and all that from you. There *is* a C formatting specifier `%s` for strings. Thus, something has clearly been lost :)

Comment: @PeteBecker: It would add consistency and potentially ease some code. Despite a lack of need, you can also convert an integer to an integer, e.g. `int x; int y = static_cast<int>(x);`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than define your own overload taking `std::string` in the `std` namespace, which is a very bad solution, just do this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string to_string(const std::string& value)
{
    return value;
}

template <typename T>
void display(T value)
{
    using namespace std;
    std::cout << to_string(value) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    display("ABC");
    display(7);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't use ADL, because the arguments have builtin type. Instead, the `display` function brings in names from `std`, so that unqualified lookup has both `std::to_string` and `::to_string` in the lookup set.

Comment: @M.M, what does ADL mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to guess why the overload is not in the standard library but here is a simple solution you can use. Instead of `std::to_string`, use `boost::lexical_cast`.

```
template <typename T>
int read(T nameOrIndex)
{
  if (!present(nameOrIndex))
    {
      throw std::invalid_argument {
          "Missing row: " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(nameOrIndex)
      };
    }
  // …
}
```

If you don't want the Boost dependency, you can easily roll your own function for this.

```
template <typename T>
std::string
to_string(const T& obj)
{
  std::ostringstream oss {};
  oss << obj;
  return oss.str();
}
```

It is obviously not optimized but might be good enough for your case.